# array: change key and replace with new one

Tags: php

I found many examples on stackexchange about replacing keys, but I can't handle my situation. I'm trying to do both: with foreach and array_map (array_walk as well) but can't get it done.

```
$arr = ["first_name"=>"a","second_name"=>"","third_name"=>"b"];

$arr = array_map(function($key, $value) {
    $key = str_replace("_name", "", $key);
    return array($key=>$value);
}, array_keys($arr), $arr);
```

output should be:

```
 $arr = ["first"=>"a","second"=>"","third"=>"b"];
```

but it's not. Can you show me both ways: foreach and array_map, how this should be done?

Comment: You can't do this with `array_map`. The function only returns values, not keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$arr = ["first_name" => "a","second_name" => "","third_name" => "b"];

foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
        $newkey = str_replace("_name", "", $key);
        $arr[$newkey] = $value;
        unset($arr[$key]);
 }
```